# How is an array of structs accessed in getStorageAt and where is it stored?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

The following code works - after changing uint to unit16 - and I find now after running it, that getStorageAt does not show the actual values. Are the values stored outside that access to that method or in memory?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CA3 {

struct Student {
        uint16 age;
    uint16 income;
    uint16 score;
    uint16 attendance;
}
Student[] public students;

function setStudent (uint16 _age, uint16 _income, uint16 _score, uint16 _attendan
ce) public {
   Student memory tempStudent = Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _scor
e, attendance: _attendance});
        students.push(tempStudent);
//students.push(Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _
attendance}));


}

}

> con.setStudent(8,1,1,1)
"0x9886c2de6ace867efedc4c06d2fa79d7148807287a827d2f31a6f01956d6b4ca"

> con.students(0)
[8, 1, 1, 1]

> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
```

The 1 appears to be somekind of index.

When I run -

```
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
> con.setStudent(8,10,10,15)
"0x2e9ad070deaa4cd044ae3d1b4673a676efde828faf5043bc1b62fdb746efb583"
> eth.pendingTransactions.length
0
> con.students(1)
[8, 10, 10, 15]
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,1)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,2)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"
```

After the second run, storage shows 2. But where is the students array stored?

I just exited the geth and entered again to find the same results. So students are not held in memory. The values are in storage. But where? Also why does getStorageAt not show them? Is there an equivalent method to show them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage

In your case, I think the first array element is at slot `keccak256(uint256(0))`.

The value at slot 0 is the length of the array.

**EDIT**

web3.js 0.2x.x code to do it:

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress,
  web3.sha3(web3.padLeft("0", 64), { encoding: 'hex' }),
  function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
);
```

Here's code to read an arbitrary index of the array:

```
var n = 1;
var startSlot = web3.toBigNumber(
    web3.sha3(web3.padLeft("0", 64), { encoding: 'hex' }));
var slot = "0x" + startSlot.add(n).toString(16);

web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, slot, function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Do we use web3.sha to find out the location? How can we check the actual storage values for that array in geth?

Comment: Yes. See my edit.

Comment: Brilliant. I tested the code and had this - 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000100010008 for "0" and when I entered "1" I had just all zeros. How would we get the elements of students(0,1,...). BTW - a brilliant answer. I just saw code ver #2 in your answer - I will test that.

Comment: This all works now. Now I have to try and understand why it works.

Comment: so is students stored in the contract storage? startslot is all 0s for one slot size (32 bytes) but why is that the start position? Is there is a link to explain this?

Comment: Yes, it's in storage. Didn't the link I provided help?

Comment: It states - Array data is located at keccak256(p) and the value corresponding to a mapping key k is located at keccak256(k . p) where . is concatenation. If the value is again a non-elementary type, the positions are found by adding an offset of keccak256(k . p). - but it does not state why that is used. So keccak is a sha of data and that is the location of a mapping key? I would like to understand this design. The contract has some storage which is then charged so I think it matters to understand how that storage is used.

Comment: `keccak256` is the hash function used. (It's called `sha3` some places, but the final SHA3 standard differs slightly.) The hashing is done to make sure there's room for what's being stored. If you declared two dynamic arrays, `Student[] students1` and `Student[] students2`, how do we make sure they don't collide as they grow? Solidity does this by choosing addresses that are far apart. `keccak256(0)` for the first and `keccak256(1)` for the second.

Comment: I guess my problem was with how storage is charged because it implied to me that a charge was being made for a lot of unused space. I take the point about allowing the array to grow. So I presume the gas costs are worked out as the array grows and there is no wasted space, and the address from the keccak256 is always available. You answer was brilliant. I think understanding storage is important due to the cost implications.

Comment: There's no actual gas charge for storage. Rather, you're charged for storing and retrieving values. So whether you write a value to address 0 or address 2^256-1, it costs the same. (None of the zeros are actually stored anywhere. The storage trie is basically a mapping of storage slots to values, and anything not explicitly in there is a zero.)

Comment: That helps a lot - to understand that access to storage costs and not actual storage.